Visual Studio Code is not suggesting code completions or syntax highlighting for Keras
In Visual Studio Code, I am not getting Keras code completion options for the text I am typing. I am
also not getting any Keras words to highlight.
For example, when I type  keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(). I am not getting recommendations of the next word after each of the dots in keras.datasets.mnist.load_data().
